# Trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 on Mac; unable to run binaries

Tags: ruby, installation, osx-mountain-lion

I am using OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2. I have looked and followed instructions to install the latest version of Ruby on my MacBook Pro, but it isn't working. Is there a simple .DMG installer out there somewhere?

Whenever I try to run a Ruby binary from the command line (e.g., `ri`, `rvm`, `ruby`), I get `command not found`.

**Edit:** I tried to post my Terminal history, but this site wouldn't let me because of the hyperlinks.

Just found this in the sidebar: http://railsinstaller.org.  Is this legit?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Looking at my history:   -bash: rvm: command not found -bash: rl: command not found -bash: ryby: command not found I can't hit return to go to a new line...

Comment: You're missing quite a few dependencies that are required for Ruby. I would suggest downloading the kit at http://railsinstaller.org/ and going through the step-by-step directions.

Comment: Thank you.  I have 18 minutes left on the download (DSL is horrible here).  I will do that.  Do I need to worry about all the crap I have installed?

Comment: Chriss-MacBook-Pro:~ CCole$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
Chriss-MacBook-Pro:~ CCole$ 
So simple.  Thanks aam1r!

Comment: @aam1r Post it as an answer!

Comment: Absolutely!!  I spent a good hour or 2 the other night and didn't find that link.  All I could find is terminal commands that left me frustrated and confused.  Thanks again!

Comment: Posted it as an answer. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing quite a few dependencies that are required for Ruby. I would suggest downloading the kit at [railsinstaller.org](http://railsinstaller.org/) and going through the step-by-step directions ([Mac](http://railsinstaller.org/mac) / [Windows](http://railsinstaller.org/windows)).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can install [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) (an alternative to RVM that is more lightweight) via the homebrew package manager. Rbenv will help you install the latest ruby builds via a sister project, ruby-build. With homebrew you will be able to install  most other dependencies you might need for developing (Redis, etc.).